# Querying the stack exchange data explorer

Tags: dataexplorer

For my research, I need to access dataset of stack overflow. I tried to access data from stack exchange data explorer but I am getting following error:Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding for the query https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/6627/top-50-most-prolific-editors.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the query takes too long and takes too many resources to solve.
The query was made in jul 2010, back then the dataset was only a fraction of what it is today, which might have made it possible to be performed. Nowadays the dataset is too large for it.

You could consider [downloading](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) the most recent dataset and perform the query on your own server.